# Difference between variable === value and value === variable?

Tags: php, zend-framework, equality

**a)**

```
  if(null === $object)
    {
    //take some action
    }
```

**b)**

```
  if($object === null)
    {
    //take some action
    }
```

I am in habit of doing like b) but in Zend-Framework I find everywhere they have done it like a) . Is there any benefits of it ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

The latter is supposed to help to avoid silly typos when you write `$a = null` instead of `$a == null` (or `$a === null`). In first case you'll get logical error, because of assignment instead of comparison, in second case - you'll get fatal error which will help you to find an issue sooner.

Comment: In javascript you run into problems with type coercion. Does PHP not do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it is used to avoid mistakes (like setting variable to `null`, not comparing them), however the `null === $object` is often considered the Bad Way (c) to avoid typos.

Answer (score 1):

The `$object === null` expression is much more human-friendly then `null === $object` 'cause second one breaks nature reading order which is left-to-right. That's why even if there is no much difference for interpreter but it's a bit harder to read by a human. Involving some logic - if you use if..else statement how it should sounds like? "If `null` equals `$object`.. Wait a minute, `null` is `null`, how can it be equal to something else? Oh, Gee, we actually comparing right-handed value to left-handed one, it's reversed stuff. So, if `$object` equals `null` then we should..". And your think this way *every time*.

My conclusion is: use `$value == const` every time you can! Long time ago people wrote `if ($value = const)` but these times have passed. Now every IDE can tell ya about such simple errors.

Comment: The nature reading order will work in both ways. Additionally the good practice is to write `NULL` lefthand for Left to Right readers as well, to prevent typos (which we do as humans). So it's more natural to take care, isn't it? Literally -1

Comment: As for me it's much easier to read `if $apple is RED` rather then `if RED is $apple`. I agree, in this case we could do typos, but I think the primary goal is to fight against code complexity and make it easy to understand. I prefer to make my code more readable and have some risk of typing `=` instead of `==` since it happens very rarely and it's pretty easy to find if follow one of clean code rules - write smallest possible functions.

Comment: Well much better to read is: `if ($apple->isRed())`. Don't mix verbs with nouns, but make nouns objects and verbs methods. My argument was more of the kind: `if (a === b)` or `if (b === a)`  are the same to read. It's a comparison (two-sided) so the natural reading *should* not matter.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right when when `a` and `b` are variables. (In my last comment I had to name variable `$apple_color`, pardon). But when there are variable and constant such as `$apple_color` and `RED` it's easer to understand `if ($apple_color == RED)` rather then `if (RED == $apple_color)`. By nature of comparsion we compare something that is in attention focus with something else. And if comparsion evaluates to false we should take the stuff and compare it to another something. In case of `RED == $apple_color` we unintentionally taking `RED` as stuff and comparing with something else

Answer (score 0):

b) is way more *readable* than a)

And a) is considered by some overcautious people as less error prone because of possible confusing `==` with `=`.
But in case of three ='s I doubt anyone will confuse it with one.

Comment: nope, it is not. it resembles the natural language, the way we speak. you can read this statement aloud and everyone around will get it's meaning right

Answer (score 0):

This a choice by the developer to attempt to stop accidential assignment of values.

The functionality is exactly the same between the two methods of comparison but in the case of "a" it stops any accidential assignment of values as you cannot assign something to null.

Answer (score -1):

The second method checks the value and type of variable against `null`, The errors should be different in tow methods.

Comment: They both check the value and type, as they both use the `===` operator. The only difference is the first one avoids typos that would result in assignment instead of comparison.